# How to use Shell to generate the specified code

Tags: shell, sed

The contents of the Localizable file are:

```
"login" = "MyLogin";
"logout" = "MyLogout";
```

I wrote the sed command is:

```
sed "s/^\"/+ (NSString *)localized_/g" "${Localizable file}" | 
sed "s/\" = \"/ { return" sed "s/^\"//g" "${Localizable file}" | 
sed "s/\" = \"/; \"/g" | 
sed 's/;[^;]*//g' | 
sed "s/ .localized; }/g"
```

I would like to generate the following code (Objective-C) based on the contents of the Localizable file:

```
+ (NSString *)localized_login {

    return @"login".localized;
}

+ (NSString *)localized_logout {

    return @"logout".localized;
 }
```

**How should i modify my sed order?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using backreference:

```
sed 's/^"\([^"]*\).*/+ (NSString *)localized_\1 { \n\n    return @"\1"\.localized;\n\n}\n/' localizable_file
```